# Room Database with Android Studio

Tags: android, database, android-studio, android-room

error: There is a problem with the query: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such table: task)

This Error is shown,
How can i possibly fix this?

I'm following [this](https://medium.com/@rohan.surve5/how-to-fetch-json-data-using-volley-and-put-it-to-recyclerview-and-store-on-room-database-for-4387280f35dc) tutorial

Comment: please post the log and your code

Comment: You may resolve your issue by this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45594432/android-room-sqlite-error-no-such-table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That tutorial is broken.

For your specific problem, change:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM task")
```

to:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Recipe")
```

and hope for the best.

Comment: Schema export directory is not provided to the annotation processor so we cannot export the schema. You can either provide `room.schemaLocation` annotation processor argument OR set exportSchema to false.
This is what I get after doing that.

Comment: That is merely a warning. If and when you start writing instrumented tests for testing Room migrations, you will need to worry about that.